# Is OK to accept multibyte unicode codepoints as recipient address for Sendmail and Postfix?

Tags: email, unicode, postfix

I am working on a server software that receives an utf-8 encoded email address to send an email to.
I permit multibyte unicode characters (emoji etc.). Then I pass that email address to Sendmail to send an email with Postfix.
Is that dangerous? I block not allowed single-byte character but I don't know:

1. if there are multibyte unicode characters to block because they are dangerous for Sendmail or Postfix;
2. if Sendmail or Postfix read the email address in single-byte way and so they could encounter not allowed bytes as part of utf-8 encoded unicode characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RFCs [6531](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6531) and [6532](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6532) document the usage of UTF-8 in email addresses, email headers, and the SMTP protocol.  Emoji are among the permitted characters, and there are addresses at my domain which consist entirely of emoji which can be used to validly address mail to me.

As long as the UTF-8 is validly encoded (that is, it encodes a valid codepoint and is not using an over-long encoding) and it is allowed by the RFCs, allowing UTF-8 email addresses (that otherwise meet the production in the RFC) is valid and encouraged, and it should pose no security problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is more formally called [Email Address Internationalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Internationalization) (EAI) and involves [RFC 6530](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6530), **[RFC 6531](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6531)**, **[RFC 6532](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6532)**, and [RFC 6533](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6533) (most notably the bolded middle two, hover for titles). [Postfix SMTPUTF8 documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPUTF8_README.html) has been around for a while, but I'm not finding much for Sendmail's support (though Wikipedia lists Sendmail [SMTPUTF8 support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTPUTF8) as experimental in 8.17.1). See also the older [RFC 2047](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047), which allows ASCII encodings for Unicode display names (but not email addresses).

There are a few security concerns here.

The primary concern is how this breaks existing systems. For example, [SPF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework) and therefore [DMARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC): [SPF macro expansion](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4408#section-8.1) allows `%{s}` and `%{l}` to refer to the sender address or its local part (username). When used in an [`exists` mechanism](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4408#section-5.7), it becomes a DNS query, and it is unclear whether this will require conversion to an [A-Label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19565551/519360)/[punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode), thus requiring updating every existing SPF implementation, or EAI local parts in exists mechanisms will be given an explicit action (e.g. assume it doesn't exist), or it will have some other workaround, or it will simply break SPF traversal.

Name mapping inconsistencies are another item to consider. One one server, `æther@example.com` may map to `ether@example.com` but another server might instead map `æther@example.info` to `aether@example.info`. This differs by convention as well as by region or language. Like [plus addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Sub-addressing) and Google's use of optional dots, this can result in interesting complications including abuse. However, unlike those methods, accounts expected to collide might instead be distinct; if you have `áaron@example.com` and I register `aaron@example.com`, I might get some of your mail.